# What are the differences among $\zeta_n^k , \zeta_n$ and $\zeta?$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, notation

What are the difference among  $\zeta_n^k , \zeta_n$  and $\zeta?$

I know that $\zeta_n=  e^{\frac{2\pi i}{n}}$ and  $\zeta_n^k=  e^{\frac{2\pi i k}{n}}$

**Note** :$\zeta_n$ denote  the first primitive $n^{th}$  root of unity

I am confused about $\zeta$

Comment: Please, provide some more context

Comment: Probably it refers some $\zeta_n$

Comment: $\zeta$ is a symbol used for all kinds of things. It's basically impossible to tell you what it means. It's like asking what the symbol $x$ means. Could be anything, really, depending on what the author wants it to mean.

Comment: @DaniloGregorinAfonso i edited

Comment: These terms are meaningless without context. Often $\zeta$ will just be the same as $\zeta_n,$ where the $n$ is assumed. But that depends.

Comment: Where did you learn what $\zeta_n$ and $\zeta_n^k$ mean? That source should define $\zeta$ before they use it.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos, but here the context is almost clear. The OP is asking about roots of unity and $\zeta$ is a common notation in such case

Comment: @jasmine, it is often denoted by $\zeta$ to mean a common notation for roots of unity. I hope the reference/source (which you are quoting) has the information.

Comment: Also i don't think it is appropriate to vote for closing the question. Instead we should suggest to develop the question.

Comment: @Why Actually, i was   reading dummit and foote book .This notation $\zeta$ mentioned in  the last  section of field theory chapter  but   not given in detail ,so i was  confused

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the context of roots of unity, $\zeta_n$ explicitly states the degree of the root; i.e., $\zeta_n = e^{2\pi i/n}$ is the "first" primitive root of the polynomial $z^n - 1$.  Then the other roots are just $\zeta_n^k$ for $k \in \{0, 1, 2, \ldots, n-1\}$, where only those $k$ satisfying $\gcd(k, n) = 1$ are primitive.

When specifying the degree of the root is not necessary because it is fixed within the context of the discussion, then for the sake of brevity, it is common practice to write $\zeta$ rather than $\zeta_n$.  For instance, suppose we are interested in a trigonometric identity related to $\zeta_7$.  Then we often omit the $7$ subscript and just write $\zeta = e^{2\pi i/7}$, because there are no other degrees we are interested in.  But if we want to talk about the product of cyclotomic polynomials with different degrees, then we *do* need to specify the subscripts.

Comment: There is also the point that we are not compelled to describe roots of unity as complex numbers. They can be more abstract, inside an algebraic closure of $\mathbb Q$ that is not necessarily imbedded in $\mathbb C$. In that case, whatever choice was made of _one_ primitive $n$-th root $\zeta_n$, for $k$ prime to $n$, $\zeta_n^k$ is just another such. Algebraically indistinguishable from $\zeta_n$. And, indeed, some of the distinctions that appear to arise by imbedding things into $\mathbb C$ are illusory.

Comment: +1 for @paulgarrett comment. I still find it amusing that roots of an irreducible polynomial are indistinguishable. This idea strikes so against what we learn in high school about roots being real or complex (or complex roots are in conjugate pairs). But often their embedding into $\mathbb{C} $ simplifies a lot of arguments.